# Angular Emit an event from a child to another through parent

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form that has 2 parts, a fixed part with the Save Button, and a modular part on top which has no submit button.
I have my own save button to do multiple tasks before actually submitting the form, and one of these tasks is to emit an Event to let the other component know that I have tried to submit so it would trigger the validation.

in the child form with the validation button (child-a), I have this output:

```
@Output() validated = new EventEmitter();
  .
  .
  .
onSave() {
    this.validated.emit();
}
```

then in the parent template, I have the following:

`<child-a (validated)="onValidated($event)"></child-a>`

then in the parent page that contains both, I added `validated` as an input to the `parentPage.ts`:

`@Input() validated;`

now I have a different child (child-b) that should listen to this `validated` event. How can I observe `validated` which is emitted from child-a to parent so I may use it in child-b?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not at all elegant/optimal but it worked.
in `parent.ts` I passed a boolean value to `child-b` like this

`<child-b [submitted]="submitForm"> </child-b>`

then in `parent.ts`, I toggled the value of submitForm

```
@Input() validated;

submitForm = false;
  .
  .
  .
onValidated() {
    this.submitForm = true;
}
```

then in `child-b.ts` I just added an input `@Input submitted;` which I use later in my code to trigger my validation.

This way I Emit an event from Child-A to the Parent, the Parent flips a boolean value that is tracked by Child-B, then Child-B would react once the boolean variable flips to `true`